# All vocal formants in order of frequency?

Tags: vowels, frequency, formants

Wondering if there's any resource online that can show the sequence of vowel pitch high to low.  I realise that frequencies vary depending on the speaker/accent/etc, but some kind of average/ballpark.  This is an incomplete, yet good, example -

[image: Text]

but there are many more vowel sounds unaccounted for by it.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any speech acoustics program is able to measure frequency. Formants are a specific kind of frequency measure – any sound can have a number of computable formants. When speaking of vowels, we usually limit the discussion to the first two or three formants, moreover people usually ignore the third formant unless there is a good reason to mention it (mainly because we don't have a heuristic for predicting it, and it is a pain in the neck to graph).

The graph above is a typical two-axis graph that plots the first formant against the separation of the first and second formants, designed to most-closely resemble the classical articulatory tongue position chart. Because there are numerous measures, they cannot be "ordered", but you can graph them as in your Goldstein graph. [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Thevowel-space-A-formant-chart-showing-the-frequencies-of-the-rst-and-second-formant_fig1_2794759) is another graph with a different arrangement. What they have in common is that they are charts of American English vowels arrangement. They both miss /ʌ/ (dunno why), but [here](https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Ekrussll/phonetics/acoustic/formants.html) is a Canadian chart that includes /ʌ/.

So what is missing? Well, a few examples are [ø, y, ɯ, ɜ]. But English doesn't have them. Vowel charts are different across languages, meaning that "i" is English if not the same as "i" in Spanish (and "i" in Mexican Spanish is not the same as "i" in Highland Ecuadorian Spanish). It is meaningful to make a claim about average formant values for the vowel phonemes /i, u, æ/ in American English, but not for "all human languages". Formant measurements are concrete numbers derived from a specific set of utterances. Nobody has measured "typical" or "average" formants of the phoneme /ø/ in all human languages that have it. You may be able to find additional numbers (which you could put in a graph), such as [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant) derived from Catford's book (which includes a wider range of vowels though these are not in a specific human language, they are his personal trained performance-standard of the IPA).